# Repeated comparisons over time between two groups

Tags: repeated-measures, biostatistics

I have to compare the mean between two groups over time. The difficulty here is that I have to make this comparison about 80 times. And it is not enough to know whether there is a difference, but I also have to say *when* it occurs.

For the context: a behavioral marker measured in 2 groups of 5 mice each, measured over and over again in different conditions, in day- and night-time, before and after some treatments etc.